# New router, old network, but devices won't talk to each other

Tags: router, firewall, norton-antivirus, xbox360

I plugged the new router in and get internet on both the computer and the Xbox 360.
The Xbox 360 only recognizes the computer when I turn the Smart Wall off in my Norton antivirus, and only when the computer is hardwired. How do I make it so that Norton will allow the computer and Xbox to talk? Reset the MAC address? I have no idea how to do this, and I'm starting to think it's the answer to my problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't reset the MAC address. That is typically fixed. Smart wall sounds a lot like a firewall. Therefore there should be a place to add/allow exceptions in Norton for certain ports. Try opening the ports listed on [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911728) site. Sorry I couldn't quote it because of the table.

I don't own an Xbox or run Windows so sorry I can't help further, but I think that is the direction you need to go in.

Edit: I forgot to mention you may need to open those ports in your new router as well. You will need to log into your router. Check the manual for the default address of your router then type it into a browser (like 192.168.1.1). Then follow the directions to open/forward ports.

Comment: I will check into this...

Answer (score 0):

Turn all of your firewalls off including the windows firewall. Remember for the windows firewall you need to stop the service as well. What version of windows do you have? If it is windows 7 see if you can see the xbox in the UPnP map (in network and sharing it is the full network map option).

Comment: Turning off all firewalls could be a potential risk. He just needs to add exceptions.

Comment: Agreed, it is not a long term solution but it will tell him if that is the problem.